# Changing AD names - what to do with Macs with local AD users

Tags: mac

We will be changing the format of our Active Directory usernames in the near future.
This is going the effect about 200 users with Macs with local home directories.

The main goal is to have the users be able to use a shorter username and we will be changing the Active Directory home folder name as well.

I thought of preemptively changing the full name on the accounts to the new username ahead of the Active Directory changes (I will upgrading RAM on most of these computers soon, so I will have a chance to be hands on) but once the Active Directory name changes are made the renamed Active Directory home folder doesn't appear in it's usual place in the dock.

I am tasked with making this change with minimal impact on users, but I have not found a method yet that doesn't involve me touching every Mac before and after the change.

We are running a mixed 10.8 & 10.9 environment.